# How to search and return string values in C# using input text file

Tags: c#

I have a log file in following format :

```
[BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 4027909 Server: nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:karansha appGUID: wx Elapsed Time: 1204ms method:bug.updateBug Date: Mon Jan 14 09:42:05 IST 2013
[BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 4027909 Server: nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:karansha appGUID: wx Elapsed Time: 1204ms method:bug.updateBug Date: Mon Jan 14 09:42:05 IST 2013
[BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 4027909 Server: nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com user:vader appGUID: wx Elapsed Time: 1204ms method:bug.updateBug Date: Mon Jan 14 09:42:05 IST 2013
[BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 4027912 Server: nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed Time: 1204ms method:bug.updateBug Date: Mon Jan 14 09:42:05 IST 2013
```

How can i manage to get all the string values say e.g. User: value, using C# ?

Comment: which type file is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression something like this @"User:(?.*?) appGUID"
and you'll get list of usernames + you can add another group to regexp with value. example below:

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("sample.txt");
        string x = reader.ReadToEnd();
        List<string> users = new List<string>();
        int numberOfUsers;

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(U|u)ser:(?<username>.*?) appGUID");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(x);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            string user = match.Groups["username"].ToString().Trim();
            if (!users.Contains(user)) users.Add(user);
        }
        numberOfUsers = users.Count;
```

Comment: Thanks for resolution, but here i am encountering one issue, using regular expressions, i am getting unique line counts, all i want is unique "User" counts from a log file. Can you please help me with that ?

Comment: What i meant to say is take for example, in my log file mentioned above, there are four lines containing 3 unique users, now lets say if  all the lines are unique, than result displayed by program is 4 because of unique lines, what i want is my program to return values according to user.

Comment: According to user, the program should return 3 in above sample log file.

Comment: check edited answer, numberOfUsers is what you need

Comment: Thanks Gratz for providing quick resolution.

Comment: One more thing i want to ask, i have a log file in which some lines have value of users in format like "User:<space>value" like for example=> "User: Karan" . How will i manage to get values for this just by modifying your mentioned code snippet ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: So that my program would return values from "User:<some value>" as well as from "User:<space><some value>" .

Comment: you should read more about regular expressions, for example here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595(v=vs.80).aspx  anyway there was a bug in my code, now it should work (added Trim function), if its ok, check my answer as correct one

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each line in the file, then apply a regular expression to that line to filter the contents.

a simple example of this is here [How to: Search Strings Using Regular Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I recently  watched a video via TekPub where Jon Skeet did this exact thing, i believe it was the regular expression video [TekPub Mastering C#](http://tekpub.com/productions/csharp4)

a site i use to test regular expressions is [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)